# MinGW-w64 link with Windows system libraries undefined reference

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw, gdi, mingw-w64

I installed msys2 and I'm using the UCRT64 environment that comes with it. I installed the mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-toolchain group of packages, which I am using to compile C++.

I have a file which compiles as a static library `libtestwin64.a` and contains this:

```
#include <windows.h> // contains <winuser.h> <wingdi.h>

void funcA() {
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL); // references to <winuser.h> cause no error. 
    HCOLORSPACE hcs = GetColorSpace(dc); // references to <wingdi.h> cause error. 
}
```

When I try to link with `libtestwin64.a` and compile an executable `g++ -I../mirr/inc   obj/Win64/three.o obj/Win64/four.o -o ../bin/test64.exe -luser32 -lgdi32 -L../mirr/lib  -ltestwin64`, it causes these `undefined reference` errors for anything from `wingdi.h`:

```
D:/software/msys/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
../mirr/lib/libtestwin64.a(one.o):one.cpp:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `__imp_GetColorSpace'
```

`ld.exe` reports no error about finding the files `libgdi32.a` etc. Adding options like `-lgdi32` to the linker doesn't change the result. Other system libraries like `libuser32.a` cause no error.

What can I do to use functions from Windows GDI through msys2?

Comment: Was `libtestwin64.a` compiled using the same toolchain?

Comment: @M.M yes like `ar rs ../lib/libtestwin64.a obj/Win64/one.o obj/Win64/two.o` `g++ -I../inc -Wall -pipe -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fstrict-aliasing -m64 -MMD -c one.cpp -o obj/Win64/one.o -MT obj/Win64/one.o`

Comment: Linking order issue, perhaps? Reorder `-ltestwin64` before `lgdi32`.